# Laravel Simple Count DB Row echo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a Laravel Beginner and after weeks learning and trying i need some help now.

I simple want count an number from my Mysql DB Table in PHP.

My code:

```
SELECT category_id FROM products WHERE category_id IN (1, 2)
```

I only know how i can make it in PHP not Laravel with Controllers.

Theres an Simple code how i can display the result in my Laravel php page without this? (i know in laravel i dont need this):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT category_id FROM products WHERE category_id IN (1, 2)";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("%d\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And in what files i must add some code thats work? Index,controller,web.php / routes? Because for example if i try:

```
{{$product->name}}
```

i get this error: "Undefined variable: product "
Must i connect every page with an Controller?

I need some very easy explain for it with example code if possible:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in Laravel to get the count of a table is

```
$count = DB::table('categories')->count();
```

Which will give you the number of rows within the table 'categories'.

You would usually put this in a controller and pass it to a view.